# How do I insert dash lines between numbers in R

Tags: r

Please help me to insert a dash after the 2nd and 4th digits of 6 digit numbers. An example is a short version of a date format: 631022.

63 is the year, 10 is the month and 22 the day.

Comment: What is the goal? Do you eventually want to convert it to a `Date`?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output format to add clarity ? You stated what the year, month and day is but it would be good to see the output string you want.

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is for the string to become an actual date, the lubridate package is awesome for this sort of thing, particularly the function `ymd(...`. That said, it will guess whether you want 2063 or 1963 and might not do it correctly. You might try this:

```
 library(lubridate)
 x <- "631022"
 ymd(paste0("19", x))
```

Result: "1963-10-22" of the class POSIXct.

Comment: Assuming lubridate's `ymd` uses the same methodology as `strptime` we know that anything less than `68` will be assumed to be prefixed by `20`: "Year without century (00–99). On input, values 00 to 68 are prefixed by 20 and 69 to 99 by 19 – that is the behaviour specified by the 2004 and 2008 POSIX standards, but they do also say ‘it is expected that in a future version the default century inferred from a 2-digit year will change’."